# SharePoint Online Provider Hosted API - no search results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, provider-hosted-app

Hi I'm using SharePoint Online and the new version of SharePoint Site.

Most things work as expected and I've not had too many problems.

Unfortunatly I'm really struggling over the Search.
I've got my context (`_sp`) and using the code examples provided.

```
 KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(_sp);
 keywordQuery.QueryText = vm.Search;
                        
        
 keywordQuery.StartRow = 0;

                      
SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(_sp);

ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
 _sp.ExecuteQuery();
```

This compiles and all works ok however I get no results back. All my tests using the REST API and on site SharePoint work ok. This, though goes through the `_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery` and despite trying to debug this with looking at the serialised query part.

```
<Query Culture=\"en-US\" EnableStemming=\"True\" EnablePhonetic=\"False\" EnableNicknames=\"False\" IgnoreAllNoiseQuery=\"True\" SummaryLength=\"180\" MaxSnippetLength=\"180\" DesiredSnippetLength=\"90\" KeywordInclusion=\"0\" QueryText=\"Housham\" QueryTemplate=\"\" TrimDuplicates=\"True\" Site=\"e9df3afe-01ea-4214-b91f-415458643633\" Web=\"b02cffd4-80f9-492d-ad21-f8e6aefe904b\" KeywordType=\"True\" HiddenConstraints=\" (NormSiteID:&quot;exxxxxx33&quot; OR SiteID:&quot;exxxxxxx33&quot;)\" />"
```

Which you can post into `/_api/search/postquery` no results are ever returned. I'm doing a full crawl which I'm hoping will give me something but at present I seem stuck.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, long story short there is a problem in creating a site app categlog for a ste collection.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-site-collection-app-catalog-for-particular-site-collection-level-solution/

This seems to create some problems with duplicate fields and then knackers up a few fields - by creating duplicates (just what our systems team told me). This then knackers up calculated fields form page and this search tool.

Deleting the fields solves the problem.